# Extract multiple values from a JSON using JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'd like to extract, using JSONPath, some values from a JSON like this one

```
{
"key": "value",
"array": [
    {
        "key": 1,
        "item": "a",
        "cod": 123
    },
    {
        "key": 2,
        "item":"b",
        "cod": 345
    },
    {
        "key": 3,
        "item": "c",
        "cod": 126
    }
]
```

}

I'd like to extract "key" AND "cod" values ....

I'm trying to use this JSONPath filter `$.array[*]['key','item']` but it doesn't work.

[image]

Is it possible? Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

this works for me

```
$.array[*].key,item
```

you just selected a wrong website , try this https://jsonpath.com/ for example or better create java script code. You jsonPath is working here

```
console.log(jsonPath(arr,("$.array[*]['key','item']")));
```

output

```
[
  1,
  "a",
  2,
  "b",
  3,
  "c"
]
```

Comment: `$.array[*]['key','item']` This is not working at https://jsonpath.com/

Comment: @ArtBindu Thanks, you are right. it only works in the code

Comment: I saw a different issue in the different compilers: https://jsonpath.com/. `$.array[*].key,item` is not working here. See the same observation at https://www.site24x7.com/tools/json-path-evaluator.html
Also, seeing different types of compilers send us different types of answers.
So, can you suggest me best compiler to understand JSON path coding deeply.

Comment: @ArtBindu There are different jsonPath libraries. And they work different. I don't know what OP uses, I am not sure that he knows it too.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the @Serge reply (thanks ...), I've retried using https://www.jsonquerytool.com/ that I've used in my initial test BUT changing the transformation used (JSONPath Plus (4.0.0) in this case, and its' working now

[image]